# Probability of winning after $k$ tickets removed from the box

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose you have a box which has 3 types of tickets: there are
$T_1$  Winning Ticket (you win the game),
$T_2$ Losing Ticket (you lose the game), and $T_3$ Retry Ticket (you get one more chance to play).

The condition is before starting the game, the organiser removes any $k$ tickets from the box at random, which means the number of tickets left are $T_1+T_2+T_3-k$.

What is the probability of winning, given $k < T_1 + T_2$.

e.g. if $T_1 = 2$, $T_2 = 3$, $T_3 = 4$ and $k = 1$,` then probability is $0.4$.

I have tried for man three hours, but i am not able to digest this question. Can anyone please explain.

Comment: Hint:  as the removal is random it does not change the distribution of ticket types.

Comment: @lulu : Does that mean I can simply ignore K?

Comment: Yes.  Think of it this way...When you go to draw your ticket you mentally decide not to choose from the last $k$ in the pile.  Clearly that doesn't alter the odds!

Comment: @lulu : I am still not able to convince myself. Lets take my example in the question. The answer would vary, if organiser would have removed T1 or T2 or T3. So its definitely dependent.

Comment: Of course if we have information about which tickets were removed then the removal matters, but we don't.  Say there were three tickets (one of each type).  I randomly remove one of them and you pick randomly from the two that remain.  In this case you can enumerate all the possibilities (there aren't many).  Convince yourself that you still have a $\frac 12$ shot at a victory.

Comment: This point always causes confusion.  Perhaps a simpler exercise is "say we had $B$ blue balls and $R$ red balls in an urn.  If you extract one at random, the probability that it is blue is clearly $\frac {B}{B+R}$.  Suppose that I randomly remove a few balls from the urn, and then you extract one at random.  show that the probability is unchanged."

Comment: @lulu : Now i am getting it slightly. Can you please point to proof of such theorem?

Comment: Don't know a reference off hand.  I'll write up an argument and post it.

Answer (score 0):

First, suppose there was no removal.  Then the probability of a win is $\frac {T_1}{T_1+T_2}$ (the $T_3$ tickets are irrelevant.  They have no impact on winning or losing.).

But the removal has no impact on the probability, hence the answer is unchanged. To see this intuitively, note that "removing $k$ tickets randomly and then selecting" is equivalent to "mentally choosing not to select from the first $k$ in the pile and then selecting ticket $k+1$".  Clearly, I think, the second has no impact on the probability.

To see it more formally, proceed by induction.  we need to prove the statement: "if we have objects of type $A,B,C,\dots$ in an urn in numbers such that the probability of drawing an $A$ at random is $p$ then after removing one object at random the probability is still $p$." To prove that:

Case I.  removed object is of type $A$.  (probability $p$).  If you started with $n$ objects in total and therefore $pn$ objects of type $A$ then we now have $pn-1$ objects of type $A$ left amongst $n-1$ total objects, hence the probability in this case is $\frac {pn-1}{n-1}$.

Case II. removed object is not of type $A$ (probability $1-p$).  The same reasoning gets us to $\frac {pn}{n-1}$.

Hence the probability of drawing an object of type $A$ after the random removal is $$p \frac {pn-1}{n-1}+(1-p)\frac {pn}{n-1}=\frac {p^2n-p+pn-p^2n}{n-1}=\frac {pn-p}{n-1}=p$$